# Using Tableview to display items in descending order with childByAutoId

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to display a data set in descending order by snap.key in a firebaseUi TableView

```
Firebase *firebaseRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"firebaseio.com/data"];

    self.dataSource = [[FirebaseTableViewDataSource alloc] initWithRef:firebaseRef cellReuseIdentifier:@"cell" view:self.tableView];

    [self.dataSource populateCellWithBlock:^(UITableViewCell *cell, FDataSnapshot *snap){
        // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below

        cell.textLabel.text = snap.value[@"Data"];


    }];
```

Right now my TableView looks like this:

- Old item
- List item
- New item

I need it displayed like this:

- New item
- List item
- Old item

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what kind of data snap.value[@"Data"] will contains ?????

Comment: I have updated the question, basically i need to sort the tableview by the snap.key where as the newest items are on top.

Answer (score 0):

Sort it; either on the server data set, or after you've retrieved your reference and before you set up your datasource.